How to disable help search shortcut (Cmd+Shift+/)
This is a default shortcut for a comment block in virtually every single code editor under the sun and there is no option to disable it under keyboard shortcuts menu in system settings. I actually disabled every single shortcut I found and it still works.
Is it possible to disable it with some terminal shenanigans I do not know about?

It may just be easier to change the shortcut to Command+/ in your editor. (By the way, the editor I regularly use (CotEditor, available from the Mac App Store) uses Command+/, as Xcode does.)

cmd+/ is for line comment and not block comment. I need both.

I see, wasn't aware of that... I've found a way to disable Command-Shift-/, could you check my answer and report back?

CommandShift/ is a global keyboard shortcut (that is, it's enabled for all apps) that moves focus to the Help menu.
Luckily, it can be disabled as follows:

Open System Preferences.

Select Keyboard.

Press the "Keyboard Shortcuts…" button.

Select "App Shortcuts".

Expand "All Applications" and uncheck "Show Help menu":


Press Done.

Quit System Settings.



yep that was it. I only have "All aplications" in this tab and didn't notice it was collapsed. Thanks!
